# MS CRM2011 SOAP request

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm-2011

All other data is imported by for some reason following three lines dont add data to the ms crm dynamics 2011?

I have three fields
my_paid : Two Options (Yes = 1; No = 0)
my_price : Currency
my_date_paid : Date and Time

```
    <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
        <c:key>my_paid</c:key>
        <c:value i:type="c:boolean">1</c:value>
    </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype> 
    <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
        <c:key>my_price</c:key>
        <c:value>' . $data->newprice . '</c:value>
    </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype> 
    <b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
        <c:key>my_date_paid</c:key>
        <c:value i:type="d:dateTime" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", time()+10800) . '</c:value> 
    </b:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you get the SoapLogger from the Dynamics CRM SDK as this will assist you with these kinds of problems.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004

The first item should be true/false not 1.

The my_price is presumably a Money column which is handled slightly differently, and your dateTime looks correct so its probably just due to the first two items.

Below is a sample from the 'Quotes' entity that should help.

```
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>freightamount</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="a:Money">
               <a:Value>1</a:Value>
            </b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>effectivefrom</b:key>
            <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:dateTime">2013-09-03T02:55:30Z</b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>willcall</b:key>
            <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:boolean">false</b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
```